# Joining three tables together

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have two tables that I was able to correctly join.  I'm trying to bring in a third table that even if in the specific year there is no data I still want null  or 0 values.  My issue is that when I join in that table i'm getting either duplicate records or no records display at all.

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM [4th grade math achievement levels] m
  INNER JOIN [4th grade reading achievement levels] r
    ON m.Location = r.Location
      AND m.TimeFrame = r.TimeFrame
      AND m.[Achievement Level] = r.[Achievement Level]
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN [4th graders who scored below proficient reading level by geographic location] g
    ON m.Location = g.Location
      AND m.TimeFrame = g.TimeFrame
WHERE m.Location = 'ohio'
  AND m.TimeFrame = 2011
```

[image]

the desired result 
Location | Achievement Level | Data | Geographic Location | Data | TimeFrame 
here is what I'm trying to combine
[image]

Comment: User left outer join to compare your value you will get a results and then you can decide where you stuck you don't have provided enough info. here

Comment: agreed, the right outer join is your problem.

Comment: It's usually recommended to not have spaces in your identifiers (table/column names, etc).  You should probably also not need separate tables per grade - this depends more on the columns in those tables, but none of your listed columns appears 4th-grader specific.

Comment: Can you add captions to each of these tables? Is the top one the result of your query? What are the bottom two? Math and Reading?

Comment: We can only see a very little bit of your data, but two tables (assuming it is the math and reading tables) have 'Ohio' in the location column, while the other has 'United States' in the location column. Is one location column essentially a country column while the others are by state?

Comment: the location column is the same in all table to define the state.  I the third column you have location for the state and geographic location such as rural, city, suburb etc.  Either way I've been looking at this there is no unique way to join my data with out creating duplicates.  I do believe i will have to add one more constraint and give the user the option to select achievement level AND geographic location.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you want a `left outer join` and not a `right outer join`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [4th grade math achievement levels] m INNER JOIN
     [4th grade reading achievement levels] r 
     ON m.location = r.location AND
        m.timeframe = r.timeframe AND
        m.[achievement level] = r.[achievement level] LEFT OUTER JOIN
        [4th graders who scored below proficient reading level by geographic location] g 
        ON m.location = g.location AND
           m.timeframe = g.timeframe 
WHERE m.location = 'ohio' AND
      m.timeframe = 2011;
```

A `left outer join` will keep all results from the `m` and `r` tables that match the conditions, producing `NULL` for values in `g` that don't match.  In your form of the query, all the rows were being taken from the `g` table (the `right outer join`).  But, because non-matching rows in the `m` table would have `NULL` values, these would be filtered out.  The result is that the `right outer join` really behaved like an `inner join`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the where clause up into your join as a join condition. When you state it in the where clause, you force the query to drop Nulls

```
select *
from [4th grade math achievement levels] m
inner join [4th grade reading achievement levels] r
on m.Location = r.Location
    and m.TimeFrame = r.TimeFrame
    and m.[Achievement Level] = r.[Achievement Level] 
    and m.Location = 'ohio' -- old where clause
    and m.TimeFrame = 2011
right outer join [4th graders who scored below proficient reading level by geographic location] g
    on m.Location = g.Location
    and m.TimeFrame = g.TimeFrame
```

Comment: this joined all the tables but created duplicates in the first two tables.

Comment: then each row in third table has a link back to two rows in one of the first two tables. There is something about how your data relates that has not been made clear to us yet.  The third table is people based, right? So your right outer join is on purpose, correct? Does each student in table 3 have a possible corresponding row in math and another in reading?

Comment: Unless you only have one student per timeframe and location, tables m & r will repeat when ever necessary. Can you post a sample of the output?

Comment: All three tables have a primary location such as location (i.e. ohio) and time frame(2011).  The third table has a location then a geographic location such as rural city suburb or other. But what the third table does not have is an achievement level.  But I will post a sample of the output shortly to make this clear as mud.  Thanks

Comment: added what the results look like running your query